# Create custom decorator in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-decorator

I am trying to create custom decorators that returns a new instance of a class and this class must be created from an injected service which I can't figure out how to access it from the decorator function

**Custom decorator**

```js
export function Collection(endpoint: string) {
  return function (constructor: any) {
    const mainService = CollectionModule.injector.get(MainService);
    return mainService.getCollection(endpoint);
  };
}
```

I want to access `MainService` from my custom decorator which I tried using the module but the `injector` property does not exist!

**The service**

```js
@Injectable()
export class MainService {

  config;

  getCollection(endpoint: string): Collection {
    return new Collection(endpoint, this.config);
  }
}
```

**Expected Usage**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @Collection('posts') postsCollection;


  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.postsCollection);
  }
}
```

#### Update

Here is a [stackblitz reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e2ynfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcollection%2Fcollection.service.ts)

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888079/angular-4-custom-decorator-injecting-services

Comment: @JonathanHamel I checked it already, but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

The value you return from a field decorator will not be used as the value for the field as you asume.

You can change the field to a property in the decorator by returning a property descriptor which will do the call to get the value of the property.

```
export function Collection(endpoint: string) {
  return function (constructor: Object, propertyName: string) {
    let descriptor: PropertyDescriptor = {
      get(this: any){
        const mainService = this["_" + propertyName] || (this["_" + propertyName] =  CollectionModule.injector.get(MainService);
        return mainService
      }
    }
    return descriptor
  };
}
```

Comment: I tried this, I am getting `Property 'injector' does not exist on type 'typeof CollectionModule'.` on `CollectionModule.injector`