# Angular service doesn't work within other service

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm using `ngx-translate` library for translations. In my components (lazy loaded routes) When I set the following, it works fine:

```
constructor( public translate:TranslateService ) {
    this.translate.setDefaultLang( this.langService.lang );
    this.translate.use( this.langService.lang );
}
```

I have my own **LangService** just to save user's selected language. I set it to `lang` property and use TranslateService there:

```
lang:string = "fa";

constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {

    // this works
    console.log(this.lang);

    // this doesn't work
    this.translate.setDefaultLang( this.lang );
    this.translate.use( this.lang );

}
```

Now I simply inject LangService to my component, but the translation doesn't work. Any idea?

Note: I imported TranslateModule into a SharedModule, and import that SharedModule in my other lazy loaded modules.

Comment: Could you add a Stackblitz example? this should work. I guess the problem comes from the initialization of the TranslateService.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add TranslateModule to exports array in SharedModule?

Is your custom LangService provided in root?

Here is an example:

1- Your custom service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class CustomTranslateService {
       constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}
}
```

2- Add TranslateModule to exports array in your SharedModule.

3- Inject your custom service in your components:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-footer',
    templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private translate: CustomTranslateService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
          // Use it here...
    }

}
```

Comment: No, the pipe I use with that service to translate doesn't work.